# maximal interval for ODE $y'=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $y(0)=0$ .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am not having good knowledge of ordinary differential equation so it may not be good question but i am unable to solve it.

I have to find maximal interval of unique solution using **Picard existence and uniqueness theorem for the ODE** $$y'=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\quad y(0)=0$$ I tried it by taking taking rectangular region $|x|\leq a, |y|\leq b$ as in existence and uniqueness theorem. Solution exists and unique in interval $(-h,h)$ where $h=\min(a,\frac{b}{M})=\min({a, \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}})$ and $M=\sup f(x)$ over rectangular region $|x|\leq a, |y |\leq b$ as usual. Now I put $a=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and find $a^4+a^2b^2=b^2$ which implies $|a|\leq 1$. So according to me $h=1$ but answer is given $h=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

> Where is my mistake?

Comment: what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Is the task about the maximal domain of any solution of the IVP or is it about making the box $R=\{(x,y):|x|\le a,~|y|\le b\}$ in the Picard-Lindelöf proof as large as possible? And does your version of the proof require a restriction due to the Lipschitz constant?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Thank you sir for editing question.  Sir i want to find interval of existence and uniqueness theorem which is given by (-h, h) where $h=max min(a, \frac{b}{M}) $ for the IVP $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, y(0) =0$.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann here $M=sup f(x))$ over rectangular region $|x|\leq a, |y |\leq b$.

Comment: Usually you also get a condition $Lh\le 1$ for the Lipschitz constant $L=\sup|f_y(x,y)|$ over this region. This can be avoided by using a modified, adapted norm on the function space, but is this the case for your task? Also consider that $a=1$ implies $b=\infty$. From lower bound considerations $|y'|\ge|y|$ you also get $b>e^a$.

Comment: But in general it appears that you are right, with the standard norm and proof construction you get that the Picard iteration is contracting for all $h<1$, with a uniform bound $e^1$, so that a limit for $h\to 1$ exists. /// More generally, the ODE is sub-linear, so that the maximal domain is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann so sir can i say that the given ODE has unique solution in $(-1, 1) $ ? i.e. $h=1$ in picard uniqueness theorem?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann sir i have to find where given ODE has  unique solution locally as in existence and uniqueness theorem.

Comment: Yes. What local solution you get depends on the proof used. Your arguments appear all to be correct for the standard proof. There is either some further condition in your version of the proof, or the $1/\sqrt2$ is associated with a different task.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you very much sir...